# Finding an image from source code of existing website

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at this site: http://www.calgaryclimbing.com/rates/ . On their footer they have very clean looking icons that link to their social media pages. I want to do the same using the same icons they are using. But when I inspect the elements It shows that they use an i tag and that the class links to some css code that uses the content property. I want to use the image icon so my questions are how can I get the image? And why was it programmed this way? Why not just use an image that you could click on?

Comment: They are probably using font-awesome which you can use on your own website too: http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: @GaijinJim is correct.  One of the best reasons to use fonts for icons is that they are vector-based and will scale well.  Plus you don't rely on loading a sprite or individual assets (just that library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't check the link you provided but it's most likely a custom font just like [Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) which you can use to put many kind of icons in your Web Site/App.

Font-Awesome use the `<i>` tag as well just like you explained.

Why using Font-Awesome?
As they  say:

> Font Awesome gives you scalable vector icons that can instantly be
>   customized — size, color, drop shadow, and anything that can be done
>   with the power of CSS